# Is there a programmatic way to determine what the most recent context is for an SEC Filing?

Tags: xbrl

If I'm trying to read an SEC XBRL filing, is there a way to programatically determine what the most recent context is? Or does the naming of a context follow a particular pattern?

For example, if I am trying to read the AAPL Q2 2020 SEC Filing, there are many different contexts, ex. FI2019Q4, FD2020Q2YTD, FI2020Q2, FD2019Q2YTD, FI2019Q4, FD2020Q2QTD, etc.

I just want the most recent quarterly numbers, ie. FI2020Q2, however I also want a way to determine this programatically so that I don't have to manually decide which context I'm interested in for every SEC filing.

Is there a systematic way to do this, or does the naming of the context follow a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SEC filings, there should be a single `dei:DocumentType` fact.  The period for this fact will correspond to the current reporting period.  You can then find other facts that have the same period, or the same end date (for instant facts).

See section 6.5.19 of the [Edgar Filer Manual Volume II](https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/specifications/edgarfm-vol2-v53.pdf)

The names of contexts are simply unique identifiers to allow them to be referenced by facts.  Whilst some tools may follow a convention in assigning them, you should not attempt to infer any meaning from them.

Also be aware that not all facts for the same period will be in the same context.  Some facts may have additional dimensions, and will therefore use a different context.

Answer (score 1):

The fact associated with the concept `dei:DocumentPeriodEndDate` has a dateTime value that corresponds to the last balance sheet date. There is another fact associated with the concept `dei:CurrentFiscalYearEndDate` that tells you the end of the fiscal period (day and month).

These two values together allow you to infer the quarterly and yearly periods.

For example, with [this filing](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=21344&accession_number=0000021344-20-000041&xbrl_type=v), we have:

Document period end date: 2020-06-26

Current fiscal year end date: --12-31

You can infer:

- that this is quarter Q2
- that the facts carrying the balance sheet values should have the instant period (date) 2020-06-26 (and there will others with the instant periods 2019-12-31, 2019-06-26, ... if the previous periods are reported again)
- that the facts carrying the income statement and cash flow statement values for Q2 should have the rough duration 2020-03-31 to 2020-06-26, for YTD 2020-01-01 to 2020-06-26, etc.

Note that you may need to add/remove a few days from the start and end periods, which requires a bit of trial and error code to find those facts that have "meaningful" periods attributable to Q2, FY, YTD, etc.

The resolution of the instant and duration periods associated with facts is **indirect**, meaning that the context id carried by the fact (like FI2019Q4) allows you to look up the context and find the period inside. I do not recommend trying to make sense of the context ids, because every filer may use a different convention. Rather, you need to dereference the context id and look at the actual XBRL periods.

Comment: I purchased your book, it was extremely helpful in getting past a lot of the lack of information and confusion over XBRL, thank you!

Comment: I am immensely happy to hear that it was useful, @steve8918! Thank you for your feedback.